# How to print a value inside json array in React JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'is24HourCheckin' of undefined
>           at employeelist.component.js:28

My response is -

```
{
  "Success": 1,
  "allemployeeslist": [
    {
      "employeeUnder": [],
      "createdTime": 1559902701,
      "isactive": true,
      "usertype": "Employee",
      "_id": "5cfa492e3cd90a0017cde1a4",
      "email": "NA",
      "pass": "rishabh20",
      "name": "Rishabh",
      "username": "Rishabh",
      "employee_id": "MN1090",
      "doj": "2015-02-09",
      "associatedDept": {
        "isactive": true,
        "_id": "5d0223f5fb6fc00e79a8d153",
        "companyId": "5cf7fba0265a1100176c1c82",
        "departmentName": "Sales",
        "createdDate": 1558615880,
        "__v": 0
      },
      "phone": "8527579800",
      "associatedCompany": {
        "is24HourCheckin": true,
        "isLeaveManagementAllowed": true,
        "timeInterval": 15,
        "distanceTravel": 300,
        "_id": "5cf7fba0265a1100176c1c82",
        "companyName": "mynukad IT Solutions",
        "companyLogo": "http://mynukad.com/img/logo.png",
        "ownerName": "Pranav Choudhary",
        "ownerPhone": "9650050610",
        "ownerAddress": "B-71, Sector 67 Noida, 201301",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "designation": "Sales Manager",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "employeeUnder": [],
      "createdTime": 1560155049,
      "isactive": true,
      "usertype": "Employee",
      "_id": "5cfe13d1bd66881a700f180f",
      "email": "satyam@gmail.com",
      "pass": "123456",
      "name": "Satyam",
      "username": "NA",
      "employee_id": "6600",
      "doj": "2015-02-09",
      "phone": "4523953001",
      "designation": "SALES MANAGER",
      "associatedCompany": {
        "is24HourCheckin": false,
        "isLeaveManagementAllowed": true,
        "timeInterval": 15,
        "distanceTravel": 300,
        "_id": "5cf91176ee51a51d4c42a1c8",
        "companyName": "Tests 6 Software",
        "ownerName": "jkl",
        "ownerPhone": "7523953001",
        "ownerAddress": "Kanpur",
        "userLimitations": 1,
        "__v": 0
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The JS function

```
componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch('/allemployeeslist').then(getresponse => {
      return getresponse.json();
    }).then(data => {
      console.log(data.allemployeeslist);
      let allempFromApi = data.allemployeeslist.map(team => {
        return {
          empname: team.name,
          empid: team.employee_id,
          empdept: data.allemployeeslist.associatedCompany.companyName,
          empdesig: team.designation
        }
      })
      this.setState({allemployeeslist: allempFromApi});
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I want to display comapanyName inside associatedCompany.

What should be the code in `componentDidMount()` method. I am using GET method.

I want some console output like. -

`console.log(data.allemployeeslist.associatedCompany.companyName);` // ABC

Comment: What did you currently try ?... also lookup Json viewer and you can view this data a bit easier.

Comment: Are you looking for Allemployeeslist[0].associatedCompany.companyName

Comment: This is my componentDidMount code - 

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/allemployeeslist')
      .then(getresponse => {
        return getresponse.json();
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data.allemployeeslist);

        let allempFromApi = data.allemployeeslist.map(team => { return { empname: team.name, empid: team.employee_id, empdept: data.allemployeeslist.associatedCompany.companyName, empdesig: team.designation } })
        this.setState({ allemployeeslist: allempFromApi });
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

Comment: Empdept:data.   Your already mapping through it , should be team.

Comment: @AnuragMishra I edited your post to add the code you provided in comments

Comment: Its working with (team.associatedCompany.companyName). But if i want to display (team.associatedDept.departmentName) then it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'departmentName' of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allemployeeslist` is an array so you won't be able to use dot syntax to get the `companyName` like it's an object.

You can map over the array to get an array of company names like this:

```
const companyNames = data
  .allemployeeslist
  .map(emp => emp.associatedCompany.companyName)

console.log(companyNames) // ["mynukad IT Solutions", "Tests 6 Software"]
```

From your **componentDidMount** code in your comment, it looks like you might just need to change `data.allemployeeslist.associatedCompany.companyName` to `team.associatedCompany.companyName`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/allemployeeslist')
    .then(getresponse => {
      return getresponse.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      let allempFromApi = data.allemployeeslist.map(team => {
        return {
          empname: team.name,
          empid: team.employee_id,
          empdept: team.associatedCompany && team.associatedCompany.companyName, // "empdept" will be undefined if no associatedCompany
          empdesig: team.designation
        }
      })
      this.setState({
        allemployeeslist: allempFromApi
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: Its working with (team.associatedCompany.companyName).
But if i want to display (team.associatedDept.departmentName) then it says 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'departmentName' of undefined.

Comment: This is because one of your objects does not have an `associatedDept`. You will need to check for this: `team.associatedDept && team.associatedDept.departmentName` to stop the TypeError.